# Problem with running angular test with jhipster

Tags: pipeline, jhipster

When I run "npm run test" then I received this error message:
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "/prefix" must be array.

I don´t know which is the problem. Is in the angular side.

Comment: Are you using Node 18?